# How do I use output from awk in another command?

Tags: bash, awk, pipeline

So I need to convert a date to a different format. With a bash pipeline, I'm taking the date from the last console login, and pulling the relevant bits out with awk, like so:

```
last $USER | grep console | head -1 | awk '{print $4, $5}'
```

Which outputs: `Aug 08` 
($4=Aug $5=08, in this case.)

Now, I want to take 'Aug 08' and put it into a `date` command to change the format to a numerical date.

Which would look something like this:

```
date -j -f %b\ %d Aug\ 08 +%m-%d
```

Outputs: 08-08

The question I have is, how do I add that to my pipeline and use the awk variables $4 and $5 where 'Aug 08' is in that date command?

Comment: You're actually asking how to use the *output* from awk, not the variables, in the other command.

Comment: What version of `date` (and the OS, etc.)? GNU date doesn't have `-j` and it uses `-f` for reading from a file. Your command would be `date -d Aug\ 08 +%m-%d`

Comment: Not sure of the exact version number -- doesn't have any sort of --version output. It's a BSD build on Mac OSX, so I put together the date options based on the man page on OS X 10.6. Only intending to run the script on mac clients, but thanks for the info; it'll be useful should I need to do something similar on Linux.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to use command substitution:

```
date ... $(last $USER | ... | awk '...') ...
```

Bash will evaluate the command/pipeline inside the `$(...)` and place the result there.

Answer (score 5):

Get `awk` to call `date`:

```
... | awk '{system("date -j -f %b\ %d \"" $4 $5 "\" +%b-%d")}'
```

Or use process substitution to retrieve the output from `awk`:

```
date -j -f %b\ %d "$(... | awk '{print $4, $5}')" +%b-%d
```

Answer (score 0):

Using back ticks should work to get the output of your long pipeline into date.

```
date -j -f %b\ %d \`last $USER | grep console | head -1 | awk '{print $4, $5}'\` +%b-%d
```

Comment: It may not matter in this case, but in general it's far better to use `$(...)` than backticks. It can be nested.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you already tried this?

```
last $USER | grep console | head -1 | awk | date -j -f %b\ %d $4 $5 +%b-%d
```

Comment: This does not work. `awk` requires parameters, and it's output is not routed to `date`'s parameters