# Timestamp to Epoch in a CSV file with GAWK

Tags: csv, awk, epoch, gawk

Looking to convert human readable timestamps to epoch/Unix time within a CSV file using GAWK in preparation for loading into a MySQL DB.

Data Example:

```
{null};2013-11-26;Text & Device;Location;/file/path/to/;Tuesday, November 26 12:17 PM;1;1385845647
```

Looking to take column 6, Tuesday, November 26 12:17 PM, and convert to epoch time for storage. All times shown will be in EST format. I realize AWK is the tool for this, but can't quite seem to structure the command. Currently have:

```
cat FILE_IN.CSV | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"}{$6=strftime("%s")} {print}'
```

However this returns:

```
{null};2013-11-26;Text & Device;Location;/file/path/to/;1385848848;1;1385845647
```

Presumably, this means I'm calling the current epoch time (1385848848 was current epoch at time of execution) and not asking `strftime` to convert the string; but I can't imagine another way to doing this.

What is the proper syntax for `gawk`/`strftime` to convert an existing timestamp to epoch?

Edit: This question seems loosely related to [How do I use output from awk in another command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452339/how-do-i-use-output-from-awk-in-another-command)

Comment: `strftime` is for formatting a time that's already in epoch timestamp form; it doesn't parse other formats.  For that you would use `strptime`, but that's not available from Gawk.  Might be time to reach for Perl.

Comment: Unfortunately stuck on a corporate system that limits me to BASH only.

Comment: Confused.  If you can call `gawk`, you can call `perl`...

Comment: I can call perl, but sysadmin requires all scripting be done only in bash.  I realize its silly, but not in a position argue.

Comment: `perl -ae 'code goes here'` is just as much a bash script as `awk 'code goes here'`.

Comment: I agree with [almost] every point (except the crazy idea that perl might be useful) :-). gawk is the right solution BUT gawk is not bash. awk is a standard UNIX tool (unlike perl) but gawk is not awk either in as much as gawk doesn't come with every UNIX installation, just some version of awk does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cat file
{null};2013-11-26;Text & Device;Location;/file/path/to/;Tuesday, November 26 12:17 PM;1;1385845647

$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/-/," ",$2); $2=mktime($2" 0 0 0")}1' file
{null};1385445600;Text & Device;Location;/file/path/to/;Tuesday, November 26 12:17 PM;1;1385845647
```

Here's how to generally convert a date from any format to seconds since the epoch using your current format as an example and with comments to show the conversion process step by step:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function cvttime(t,     a) {
    split(t,a,/[,: ]+/)
    # 2013 Tuesday, November 26 10:17 PM
    #  =>
    #    a[1] = "2013"
    #    a[2] = "Tuesday"
    #    a[3] = "November"
    #    a[4] = "26"
    #    a[5] = "10"
    #    a[6] = "17"
    #    a[7] = "PM"

    if ( (a[7] == "PM") && (a[5] < 12) ) {
        a[5] += 12
    }
    # => a[5] = "22"

    a[3] = substr(a[3],1,3)
    # => a[3] = "Nov"

    match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",a[3])
    a[3] = (RSTART+2)/3
    # => a[3] = 11

    return( mktime(a[1]" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6]" 0") )
}

BEGIN {
    mdt ="Tuesday, November 26 10:17 PM"
    secs = cvttime(2013" "mdt)
    dt = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",secs)
    print mdt ORS "\t-> " secs ORS "\t\t-> " dt
}
$ awk -f tst.awk
Tuesday, November 26 10:17 PM
        -> 1385525820
                -> 2013-11-26 22:17:00
```

I'm sure you can modify that for the current problem.

Also, if you don't have gawk you can write the cvttime() function as (borrowing @sputnik's `date` command string):

```
$ cat tst2.awk
function cvttime(t,     cmd,secs) {
    cmd = "date -d \"" t "\" '+%s'"
    cmd | getline secs
    close(cmd)
    return secs
}

BEGIN {
    mdt ="Tuesday, November 26 10:17 PM"
    secs = cvttime(mdt)
    dt = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",secs)
    print mdt ORS "\t-> " secs ORS "\t\t-> " dt
}
$
$ awk -f tst2.awk
Tuesday, November 26 10:17 PM
        -> 1385525820
                -> 2013-11-26 22:17:00
```

I left srtftime() in there just to show that the secs was correct - replace with `date` as you see fit.

For the non-gawk version, you just need to figure out how to get the year into the input month/date/time string in a way that `date` understands if that maters to you - shouldn't be hard.

Comment: This just about answers the question, but was looking to convert column $6 instead of $2.  Difference being the format; "Tuesday, November 26 12:17 PM".
Very helpful for getting me there, been playing around with options.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that. Since that field doesn't have a year - can we use the date from $2 with the time from $6 or how else should we determine the year?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show in general how to convert from any date format to seconds since the epoch - you can just tweak to provide the year however you see fit.

Comment: Yes, fair to assume year in $2 will be the same and thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for accepting the answer, and I just added a non-gawk version of the cvttime() function in case you find that your sys admin doesn't consider gawk to be acceptable after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert date to epoch with this snippet :

```
$ date -d 'Tuesday, November 26 12:17 PM' +%s
1385464620
```

So finally :

```
awk -F";" '{system("date -d \""$6"\" '+%s'")}' file
```

Thanks @Keiron for the snippet.

Comment: Was trying precisely this earlier, but couldn't think of a way to call the command for each line of the CSV. Is there a way to embed something like:
date -d $6 '+%s'

Comment: This was the code I was using in that approach: 
`cat FILE_IN.csv | awk -F";" '{system("date -d "$6" '+%s'")}'`

Comment: Found the error in the syntax
`awk -F";" '{system("date -d \""$6"\" '+%s'")}'`